# Как распаковать 7-zip архив?

Tags: c#, 7z

Как мне распаковать 7-zip архив в указанную папку с заменой файлов, желательно не прибегая к сторонним программам (используя библиотеки)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я бы все-таки рассмотрел вариант с вызовом внешней программы. Дело в том что это понятно! Любая внешняя программа легко заменяется на другую и для этого достаточно всего двух параметров в конфигурационном файле $7zAppPath, $7zAppParams.
Программисту, кроме Вас, будет легче будет понять работу функций callExternalArchivator() ибо там наверняка 5 строк, ну 8 на обработку ошибок и записи в лог-файл. Если же библиотеку, то надо показать какие исходные файлы нужны, а если обновилась библиотека, то что из нее нужно просмотреть внимательно, чтобы новые изменения в либе не сломали текущее. Другими словами, внешняя прога всегда выигрывает перед либой. Не надо усложнять там где этого можно избежать!

Comment: использовал 7za.exe

Answer (score 4):

[FAQ, однако](http://7-zip.org.ua/ru/faq.html), раздел "Вопросы разработчиков"

Answer (score 2):

Библиотека, включает в себя код на C#: http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

Внешнюю программу я бы включать не стал, т.к.:

1. Ее придется таскать с собой или иметь установленной на компьютере и настраивать путь к ней.
2. Обработка ошибок в случае использования внешнего процесса не блещет удобством.